# Android Custom Listview with overlapping views

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

I want to implement a listview which looks sth like this below,
Where the red squares are going to be buttons. And rows should me movable (drag and drop) and also deletable

[image: Custom List View]

I tried to create the red buttons as a different layout and make the "dividerHeight" as a minus value, but when i did that the row below is overlapping the button above.

Can you help me with it?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Comment: Can you post you xml file?

Comment: Which xml? The thing is i dont know how to do the implementation so the xml file i have  is actually useless

Comment: <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="-10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Again like i said, the layout file is useless. I am just asking ideas about how i can put that red square between two listview rows ?